Webpack Module Parsing Error: Unexpected Token - No Loaders Configured
I am encountering an issue with my webpack configuration while trying to build my project. When webpack attempts to parse a specific file, it throws the following error:
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2013:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     unregister() {
|         document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
>         this.darkMedia?.removeEventListener("change", this.darkMediaCallback);
|         this.unobserve();
|     }

This error message suggests that webpack encountered an unexpected token while parsing the file, and it doesn't have a loader configured to handle this file type. The file in question appears to be a JavaScript file, and the error occurs at line 2013, column 23.
I have already checked my webpack configuration and ensured that appropriate loaders are set up to handle JavaScript files. However, the error persists, and I'm not sure how to proceed in resolving it.
webpack.config.js
      const path = require('path');

module.exports = (config, { isProd, isDev, isTest }) => {
  /**
   * Customize the webpack by modifying the config object.
   * Consult https://webpack.js.org/configuration for more information
   */

  return {
    ...config,
    performance: {
      ...config.performance,
      hints: false,
    },
    module: {
      ...config.module,
      rules: [
        ...config.module.rules,
        {
          test: /index\.ts$/,
          include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/feature-library/')],
          use: 'import-glob',
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/utils/feature-loader/')],
          use: 'import-glob',
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx$/,
          include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/utils/feature-loader/')],
          use: 'import-glob',
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Find any fixes, i am also facing the same issue
